# Why doesn't the algorithm for partitioning even and odd numbers in an array work for partitioning around a pivot?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort, partitioning

We use the following algorithm to bring all even to the left and all odd to the right side of the array:

```
    def evenOddPartition(self,nums):
    # partition an array such that all even are on the left
    # and all odd are on the right

    i = 0
    j = len(nums) - 1

    while i < j:
        ## if i is even skip this index
        if nums[i]%2 == 0:
            i+=1
        elif nums[j] %2 == 0:
            ## if nums[i] is odd and nums[j] is even
            nums[i],nums[j] = nums[j],nums[i]
            j-= 1
        else:
            ## both are odd 
            ## decrement j (i.e try to see if there is any other even before it)
            j-=1

    return nums
```

Even/Odd is a binary classification like true false.

My question is now why we can't apply this same binary classification to a problems like this:

Consider this array:
y = [2,3,5,-100,100,5,5,6,3,5]

And you are asked to move all elements <= 5 to the left side and all > 5 to the right side:

Using the same logic as the Even/Odd problem, I present this code

```
    def tryTwo(self,nums):
    pivot = 5

    i = 0
    j = len(nums) - 1

    while i < j:
        if nums[i] < pivot:
            i+=1
        elif nums[i] == pivot:
            i+=1
        elif nums[i] > pivot:
            if nums[j] <= pivot:
                nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
                j-=1

            else:
                j-=1
        else:
            j-=1

    return nums
```

However, this code outputs [2, 3, 5, -100, 5, 5, 5, 3, 6, 100], which is the wrong answer. The correct answer is something like this

[2, 3, -100, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 100, 6]

What am I missing here? Is there a bug in my second code?

Comment: All elements <= 5 **are** to the left of elements > 5. Are you asking why the values are in that specific order instead of what you expected?

Comment: @Blastfurnace how? 3 is <= 5 but is to the RIGHT of 5. It should be to the left.

Comment: You are swapping when the `<= pivot` test is true. The code appears to be doing that. Do you want a three-way partition with elements <5, followed by those =5, and then >5?

Comment: @Blastfurnace, thanks for responding. Right, I am swapping when the number at j is <=5, but then why does my answer contain values <5 to the RIGHT of 5. For example 5,5,5 and then 3?

Comment: Both 3 and 5 are <=5 and I don't see where your code guarantees a specific order of those two values. They are ordered correctly in the sense of being to the left of the >5 values. Note: I am very bad with Python so I should let someone else help you.

Comment: @Blastfurnace i'm referring to the index 7. Why is this 3 there? Shouldn't it be to the left of 5?

Comment: At this like the "partition in place" is what you want http://p-nand-q.com/python/algorithms/sorting/partitioning.html

Comment: After swapping `num[i]` and `num[j]`, you forgot to increase `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi :) You stated that the task you're given is

> You are asked to move all elements <= 5 to the left side and all >
>   5 to the right side

Which means that the output  `[2, 3, 5, -100, 5, 5, 5, 3, 6, 100]` is perfectly valid.

All the elements that are less than **OR** equals to 5 are moved to the left side of the list

`[2, 3, 5, -100, 5, 5, 5, 3,`.

And the others are moved to the right side

`6, 100]`.

As Blastfurnace mentioned, your code treats every number below 6 as the same thing, and doesn't have any sorting mechanism for those numbers. So it makes sense for 3 to be after 5 (since these numbers aren't sorted).

If you want all the elements that are less than 5 to the left, every 5s to the middle and everything larger than 5 to the right, you will need a different algorithm (or just use a sorting algorithm).